# regarding receiving sms using symbian c++

Tags: c++, sms, symbian

Is it possible to retrieve SMS messages on Symbian?
I would like to transfer the messages via bluetooth to another device in an automobile.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to use the [Symbain messaging framework](http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_3rd_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/html/SDL_93/doc_source/guide/Messaging-subsystem-guide/MessagingGuide/index.html) to create a messaging client application that will observe the incomming sms messages from the messaging server.

I found this [example](http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/Handle_Incoming_SMS_Messages) which may help.